# uninitialized constant A::B (NameError)

Tags: ruby, initialization, constants, nameerror

This works:

```
class A
    def m1
         b = B.new
    end
end

class B
end
```

This fails - why?

```
class A
   b = B.new
end

class B
end
```

Error message "'': uninitialized constant A::B (NameError)" is rased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, in the second code, `b = B.new` is evaluated before `B` is defined.

Comment: But in the first case - it seems that class B is not defined too (similar to the second case) - but it still works in the first case ...

Comment: yes, thank you. Once I created object A and a called method m1 - I got the same error. Now it makes sense :-)